# How to convert an image into 2d array of its bytes, and then back to an image using the same array?

Tags: java

Before anybody rightly points it out, I know there are multiple questions exactly like this on the website. However, they all use `ImageIO` library and that is currently not present in the newer JDKs anymore.

I tried using the older JDK 1.8 but my file wouldn't even build and run properly. I got a JNI error. Now I know that I can right click on the class containing main method and select "run as Java application". However, I want to make an android application with specific functionality, and I don't want any workarounds because they may behave unexpectedly in Android Studio.

I have edited the question to remove a part that has been answered. Thanks @chuckskull. I missed that obvious answer.

Comment: `[B@70177ecd` is the reference id to the array. You have to iterate it to print the data to logs or stdout.

Comment: Are you actually looking for a replacement for JAI/ImagIO?

Comment: Which version of JDK are you using? `ImageIO` library is [available in Java 13](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/imageio/package-summary.html) as well.

Comment: Where is your code? Without any code it looks like a hypothetical question, and that makes it vulnerable to closing on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path path = Paths.get("your path");
        try{
            byte[] arr = Files.readAllBytes(path);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception");
        }
    }
}
```

This prints out the byte array as an array of integers, so the file should be converted correctly. I have used OpenJDK 14. Not sure what's the best way to turn it into a 2D array with just nio though.